# XElement.Parse not preserving whitespaces

Tags: c#, parsing, xelement

I have the following stored in a string:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html ...>
   <body>        
      <ui:composition>    
         <h:form>
            <corejsf:planet name="mercury" 
                            image="#{resource['images:Mercury.gif']}"/>
          </h:form>     
      </ui:composition>
   </body>
</html>
```

I know that it is a valid XML file so I am using XElement.Parse to read it but I detected that it is not preserving the whitespaces between the `name` and `image` attributes.

I am reading the XML using the LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace. All the other whitespaces are being preserved except the ones between attributes.

Any idea why?

thanks

Comment: If it were preserved, how would you read the text between attributes?

Comment: What do you mean? All the whitespaces in the code above do not appear except between those 2 attributes. but the attributes appear of course.